# SQL date/cost Statement not outputting to graph in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, charts, visual-studio-2015

I have created a number of graphs in my Asp.net (c#) project and they all work well. They are basically all select statements that output cost against type, cost against frequency etc. However, when I try and plot cost (y axis) against date (x axis) nothing is displayed at all. No error message, just doesn't work. My cost format is a double and my date is in a String (dd/MM/yyyy format). The idea is to group every cost thats on the 27/02/16 and display it, every cost on the 28/02/16 and display it, 29/02/16 etc etc
Below is my statement

```
SELECT SUM(IncCost), IncDate FROM Incomings GROUP BY IncDate ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103)
```

[image: This is my Incomings table data]

Maybe there is something blatantly obvious wrong.

The type of graph will be a line graph, although this is irrelevant at the moment. Normally when I create a graph in visual studio once I do the statement I have the option to set my x and y axis, however this option doesn't appear for this query.
Date will be on the x axis and cost will be on the y axis. So for each date, the total amount of cost for that day will be plotted  Thanks in advance for any help!

This is code for a working chart

```
<asp:Chart ID="incomingChart" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnLoad="incomingChart_Load" Width="519px">
                  <Series>
                      <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="IncType" YValueMembers="Column1" ChartType="Pie" YValuesPerPoint="2">
                      </asp:Series>
                  </Series>
                  <ChartAreas>
                      <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                      </asp:ChartArea>
                  </ChartAreas>
              </asp:Chart>
              <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
 protected void incomingChart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT IncType, SUM(IncCost)FROM Incomings where AspNetUsersId = '" + userId + "' GROUP BY IncType";
    }
```

It doesn't even get this far for this one, which means it's a problem in the SQL Code

Comment: Not sure I understand... what kind of graphs?  How are cost and date plotted in the graph?  I think I get what you're trying to accomplish...

Comment: The type of graph will be a line graph, although this is irrelevant at the moment. Normally when I create a graph in visual studio once I do the statement I have the option to set my x and y axis, however this option doesn't appear for this query.

Comment: Date will be on the x axis and cost will be on the y axis. So for each date, the total amount of cost for that day will be plotted

Comment: This query should give you a sum of the cost for each date.  So, it really depends on what your graph is looking for.  Can you give us a graph and query for one that works as well as the graph code for the one that doesn't?

Comment: That's it updated now